# How to retrieve bulk data with all attributes by typeName in Apache Atlas

Tags: atlas, apache-atlas

when i create a table in atlas to store connection datas (POST)

http://localhost:21000/api/atlas/v2/types/typedefs

```
{
    "entityDefs": [
        {
            "name": "Connection",
            "attributeDefs": [
                {
                    "name": "name",
                    "typeName": "string",
                    "isIndexable": true
                },
                {
                    "name": "description",
                    "typeName": "string",
                    "isOptional": true
                },
                {
                    "name": "jdbcURL",
                    "typeName": "string",
                    "isOptional": true
                }  
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

an example to import a data (POST)
http://localhost:21000/api/atlas/v2/entity/bulk

```
{
    "entities": [
        {
               "typeName": "Connection",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Connection test",
                "description": "Connection test asd",
                "jdbcURL": "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/example_db"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

to revitire bulk data GET request example

http://localhost:21000/api/atlas/v2/search/dsl?limit=25&offset=0&typeName=Connection&_=1701676939062

response is here

```
 {
            "typeName": "Connection",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Connection test",
                "description": "Connection test asd"
            },
            "guid": "16437ca0-c2fc-4019-9fc7-047f922d5d24",
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "displayText": "Connection test",
            "classificationNames": [],
            "classifications": [],
            "meaningNames": [],
            "meanings": [],
            "isIncomplete": false,
            "labels": []
        }
```

As you see only two attributes are shown in response.
where are the others or how i can get all Connection datas with all attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use basic search to query entities with specified attributes.

```
POST http://localhost:21000/api/atlas/v2/search/basic

{
     "typeName": "Connection",
     "excludeDeletedEntities": true,
     "offset":                 0,
     "limit":                  25,
     "attributes": [ "qualifiedName", "jdbcURL" ]
}
```

For rest api documentation: https://atlas.apache.org/api/v2/resource_DiscoveryREST.html#resource_DiscoveryREST_searchWithParameters_POST